# Visualforce Controller to Enter Approval Process

Tags: visualforce, approval-process

I have a Visualforce page that is designed to allow an approver to either approve/reject an Opportunity as a Final decision, or approve the Opportunity and then send it on for another approval.  The VF page provides 2 buttons to allow the user to do this and the buttons call in Javascript functions.  I would like to convert those Javascript functions into a controller to use with the VF page as it would allow me to do a few other things, but I'm not quite sure how to do so.  The code I have so far is below:

**Existing VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" >

<script src="/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js"/>
<script src="/soap/ajax/26.0/apex.js"/>
<script src="/support/console/27.0/integration.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
   sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!GETSESSIONID()}";
   function vp()
   {
       var opp = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
       opp.id = "{!Opportunity.Id}";
       var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE processInstance.TargetObjectId='{!Opportunity.Id}'");
       var approvals = result.getArray("records");
       opp.AppRejStat__c = "{!$Label.App_VP}";
       var approvalID = approvals[0].Id;
       window.open('/p/process/ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager?id='+approvalID);
       sforce.connection.update([opp]);
       return this;
   };
function final()
   {
       var opp = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
       opp.id = "{!Opportunity.Id}";
       var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE processInstance.TargetObjectId='{!Opportunity.Id}'");
       var approvals = result.getArray("records");
       opp.AppRejStat__c = "{!$Label.App_Final}";
       var approvalID = approvals[0].Id;
       window.open('/p/process/ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager?id='+approvalID);
       sforce.connection.update([opp]);
       return this;
   };

<apex:form >

<div style="text-align: left"><p/>

    <apex:commandButton Value="Approve/Reject - Final" onClick="final();"/>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <apex:commandButton Value="Approve - Send to VP" onClick="vp();"/>

</div>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take define your custom controller and add your logic in the Apex class.
Take help from following links on how to create a custom controller and how to define approval process logic in an Apex class:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_def.htm
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_custom_controllers
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_process_example.htm

Comment: Thanks.  I know how to enter an approval process from the beginning in a controller.  I don't know how to enter one that is already in progress.